# Ruby Gems fetching fails in Apache Netbeans 11 with Ruby2.6 while it works with Ruby2.4

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-11

I have been using Netbeans on Windows since a few years now, even before it became Apache Netbeans. I am still happily using *Ruby2.4 + MSYS2* along with the Ruby plugin (Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal can be used in Netbeans 11.0 IDE smoothly) in Apache Netbeans IDE 11.0 and it helps me debug the Ruby code very well with the Fast Debugger installed (*ruby-debug-ide* gem) .
However, I must move to Ruby2.6.3 due to some restrictions. Hence I installed all the gems those I saw in Ruby 2.4 to Ruby 2.6 environment and expected that it would work.

Tools >> Ruby Platforms >> (Select platform) **Ruby 2.4.1-p111** >> Gem Manager >> (***Shows perfectly all the installed***) Ruby Gems

Similarly

Tools >> Ruby Platforms >> (Select platform) **Ruby 2.6.3-p62** >> Gem Manager >> **Gems Fetching failed**.

[Selecting Ruby 2.6.3 Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrXmT.png)

[Gems fetching failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IPwR.png)

After looking at some old documentation on Netbeans wiki page for Rubygems, I found this [for Ruby Gems Fetching Failed](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyGems) It says that, the NetBeans just uses *gem* tool in the background. If the gems fetching fails, be sure to check whether it works from command line, particularly the following commands:

gem list --local --details

gem list --remote --details (I don't have any remote gems, so no results for this one)

```
PS C:\Tools> gem list --local --details

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (6.0.0, 3.2.22.5)
    Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
    Homepage: https://rubyonrails.org
    License: MIT
    Installed at (6.0.0): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (3.2.22.5): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A toolkit for building modeling frameworks (part of Rails).

activeresource (3.2.22.5)
    Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
    Homepage: http://www.rubyonrails.org
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    REST modeling framework (part of Rails).

activesupport (6.0.0, 3.2.22.5)
    Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
    Homepage: https://rubyonrails.org
    License: MIT
    Installed at (6.0.0): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (3.2.22.5): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A toolkit of support libraries and Ruby core extensions extracted
    from the Rails framework.

archive-tar-minitar (0.6.1)
    Author: Austin Ziegler
    Homepage: https://github.com/halostatue/minitar/
    Licenses: Ruby, BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    'archive-tar-minitar' has been deprecated; just install 'minitar'.

bigdecimal (1.4.1)
    Authors: Kenta Murata, Zachary Scott, Shigeo Kobayashi
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal
    License: ruby
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Arbitrary-precision decimal floating-point number library.

binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
    Author: John Mair (banisterfiend)
    Homepage: http://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Retrieve the binding of a method's caller. Can also retrieve
    bindings even further up the stack.

builder (3.0.4)
    Author: Jim Weirich
    Homepage: http://onestepback.org
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Builders for MarkUp.

bundler (1.17.2)
    Authors: André Arko, Samuel Giddins, Colby Swandale, Hiroshi
    Shibata, David Rodríguez, Grey Baker, Stephanie Morillo, Chris
    Morris, James Wen, Tim Moore, André Medeiros, Jessica Lynn Suttles,
    Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Homepage: http://bundler.io
    License: MIT
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    The best way to manage your application's dependencies

byebug (9.0.6)
    Authors: David Rodriguez, Kent Sibilev, Mark Moseley
    Homepage: http://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Ruby 2.0 fast debugger - base + CLI

cmath (1.0.0)
    Author: Tadayoshi Funaba
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/cmath
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides Trigonometric and Transcendental functions for complex
    numbers

coderay (1.1.1)
    Author: Kornelius Kalnbach
    Homepage: http://coderay.rubychan.de
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Fast syntax highlighting for selected languages.

concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    Authors: Jerry D'Antonio, Petr Chalupa, The Ruby Concurrency Team
    Homepage: http://www.concurrent-ruby.com
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Modern concurrency tools for Ruby. Inspired by Erlang, Clojure,
    Scala, Haskell, F#, C#, Java, and classic concurrency patterns.

csv (3.0.9)
    Authors: James Edward Gray II, Kouhei Sutou
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/csv
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    CSV Reading and Writing

date (2.0.0)
    Author: Tadayoshi Funaba
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/date
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A subclass of Object includes Comparable module for handling dates.

dbm (1.0.0)
    Author: Yukihiro Matsumoto
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/dbm
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides a wrapper for the UNIX-style Database Manager Library

debase (0.2.4, 0.2.2)
    Author: Dennis Ushakov
    Homepage: https://github.com/denofevil/debase
    License: MIT
    Installed at (0.2.4): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (0.2.2): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    debase is a fast implementation of the standard Ruby debugger
    debug.rb for Ruby 2.0

debase-ruby_core_source (0.10.5, 0.9.9)
    Authors: Mark Moseley, Gabriel Horner, JetBrains RubyMine Team
    Homepage: http://github.com/os97673/debase-ruby_core_source
    License: MIT
    Installed at (0.10.5): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (0.9.9): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provide Ruby core source files

debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    Author: John Mair (banisterfiend)
    Homepage: https://github.com/banister/debug_inspector
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A Ruby wrapper for the MRI 2.0 debug_inspector API

did_you_mean (1.3.0)
    Author: Yuki Nishijima
    Homepage: https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    "Did you mean?" experience in Ruby

e2mmap (0.1.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/e2mmap
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Module for defining custom exceptions with specific messages.

etc (1.0.1)
    Author: Yukihiro Matsumoto
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/etc
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides access to information typically stored in UNIX /etc
    directory.

fcntl (1.0.0)
    Author: Yukihiro Matsumoto
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/fcntl
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Loads constants defined in the OS fcntl.h C header file

ffi (1.11.1)
    Platform: x64-mingw32
    Author: Wayne Meissner
    Homepage: http://wiki.github.com/ffi/ffi
    License: BSD-3-Clause
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Ruby FFI

fiddle (1.0.0)
    Authors: Aaron Patterson, SHIBATA Hiroshi
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/fiddle
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A libffi wrapper for Ruby.

fileutils (1.1.0)
    Author: Minero Aoki
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/fileutils
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Several file utility methods for copying, moving, removing, etc.

forwardable (1.2.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/forwardable
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides delegation of specified methods to a designated object.

gdbm (2.0.0)
    Author: Yukihiro Matsumoto
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/gdbm
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Ruby extension for GNU dbm.

hashie (3.5.6)
    Authors: Michael Bleigh, Jerry Cheung
    Homepage: https://github.com/intridea/hashie
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Your friendly neighborhood hash library.

i18n (1.6.0, 0.9.5)
    Authors: Sven Fuchs, Joshua Harvey, Matt Aimonetti, Stephan Soller,
    Saimon Moore, Ryan Bigg
    Homepage: http://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n
    License: MIT
    Installed at (1.6.0): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (0.9.5): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    New wave Internationalization support for Ruby

image_size (1.1.5)
    Authors: Keisuke Minami, Ivan Kuchin
    Homepage: http://github.com/toy/image_size
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Measure image size using pure Ruby

io-console (0.4.7)
    Author: Nobu Nakada
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/io-console
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Console interface

ipaddr (1.2.2)
    Authors: Akinori MUSHA, Hajimu UMEMOTO
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/ipaddr
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A class to manipulate an IP address in ruby

irb (1.0.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/irb
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Interactive Ruby command-line tool for REPL (Read Eval Print Loop).

json (2.1.0)
    Author: Florian Frank
    Homepage: http://flori.github.com/json
    License: Ruby
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    JSON Implementation for Ruby

levenshtein (0.2.2)
    Author: Erik Veenstra
    Homepage: http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/levenshtein/index.html
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Calculates the Levenshtein distance between two byte strings.

linecache2 (1.4.0)
    Author: R. Bernstein
    Homepage: http://github.com/rocky/rb-linecache2
    License: GPL2
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Module to read and cache Ruby program files and file information

logger (1.3.0)
    Author: SHIBATA Hiroshi
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/logger
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides a simple logging utility for outputting messages.

lru_redux (1.1.0)
    Authors: Sam Saffron, Kaijah Hougham
    Homepage: https://github.com/SamSaffron/lru_redux
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    An efficient implementation of an lru cache

matrix (0.1.0)
    Author: Marc-Andre Lafortune
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/matrix
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    An implementation of Matrix and Vector classes.

method_source (0.8.2)
    Author: John Mair (banisterfiend)
    Homepage: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    retrieve the sourcecode for a method

mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    Authors: Luis Lavena, Mike Dalessio, Lars Kanis
    Homepage: http://github.com/flavorjones/mini_portile
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Simplistic port-like solution for developers

minitar (0.6.1)
    Author: Austin Ziegler
    Homepage: https://github.com/halostatue/minitar/
    Licenses: Ruby, BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    The minitar library is a pure-Ruby library that provides the ability
    to deal with POSIX tar(1) archive files

minitar-cli (0.6.1)
    Author: Austin Ziegler
    Homepage: https://github.com/halostatue/minitar-cli/
    Licenses: Ruby, BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    <tt>minitar-cli</tt> is a pure-Ruby command-line tool that uses
    {minitar}[https://github.com/halostatue/minitar] to provide a
    command-line tool, +minitar+, for working with POSIX tar(1) archive
    files

minitest (5.11.3)
    Author: Ryan Davis
    Homepage: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    minitest provides a complete suite of testing facilities supporting
    TDD, BDD, mocking, and benchmarking

multi_json (1.13.1)
    Authors: Michael Bleigh, Josh Kalderimis, Erik Michaels-Ober, Pavel
    Pravosud
    Homepage: http://github.com/intridea/multi_json
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A common interface to multiple JSON libraries.

mutex_m (0.1.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/mutex_m
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Mixin to extend objects to be handled like a Mutex.

net-telnet (0.2.0)
    Author: SHIBATA Hiroshi
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/net-telnet
    License: ruby
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides telnet client functionality.

nokogiri (1.10.3)
    Platform: x64-mingw32
    Authors: Aaron Patterson, Mike Dalessio, Yoko Harada, Tim Elliott,
    Akinori MUSHA, John Shahid, Lars Kanis
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Nokogiri (鋸) is an HTML, XML, SAX, and Reader parser

openssl (2.1.2)
    Authors: Martin Bosslet, SHIBATA Hiroshi, Zachary Scott, Kazuki
    Yamaguchi
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/openssl
    License: Ruby
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    OpenSSL provides SSL, TLS and general purpose cryptography.

ostruct (0.1.0)
    Author: Marc-Andre Lafortune
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/ostruct
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Class to build custom data structures, similar to a Hash.

power_assert (1.1.3)
    Author: Kazuki Tsujimoto
    Homepage: https://github.com/k-tsj/power_assert
    Licenses: 2-clause BSDL, Ruby's
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Power Assert for Ruby

powerbar (1.0.18)
    Author: Moe
    Homepage: https://github.com/busyloop/powerbar
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    The last progressbar-library you'll ever need

prime (0.1.0)
    Author: Yuki Sonoda
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/prime
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Prime numbers and factorization library.

pry (0.10.4)
    Authors: John Mair (banisterfiend), Conrad Irwin, Ryan Fitzgerald
    Homepage: http://pryrepl.org
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    An IRB alternative and runtime developer console

pry-byebug (3.4.2)
    Authors: David Rodríguez, Gopal Patel
    Homepage: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Fast debugging with Pry.

pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
    Author: John Mair (banisterfiend)
    Homepage: https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Walk the stack in a Pry session

psych (3.1.0)
    Authors: Aaron Patterson, SHIBATA Hiroshi, Charles Oliver Nutter
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/psych
    License: MIT
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Psych is a YAML parser and emitter

rake (12.3.3, 12.3.2)
    Authors: Hiroshi SHIBATA, Eric Hodel, Jim Weirich
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/rake
    License: MIT
    Installed at (12.3.3): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (12.3.2): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Rake is a Make-like program implemented in Ruby

rdoc (6.1.0)
    Authors: Eric Hodel, Dave Thomas, Phil Hagelberg, Tony Strauss,
    Zachary Scott, Hiroshi SHIBATA, ITOYANAGI Sakura
    Homepage: https://ruby.github.io/rdoc
    License: Ruby
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    RDoc produces HTML and command-line documentation for Ruby projects

rexml (3.1.9)
    Author: Kouhei Sutou
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/rexml
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    An XML toolkit for Ruby

rss (0.2.7)
    Author: Kouhei Sutou
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/rss
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Family of libraries that support various formats of XML "feeds".

ruby-dbus (0.10.0)
    Author: Ruby DBus Team
    Homepage: https://trac.luon.net/ruby-dbus
    License: LGPL v2.1
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Ruby module for interaction with D-Bus

ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22)
    Author: Markus Barchfeld, Martin Krauskopf, Mark Moseley, JetBrains
    RubyMine Team
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    IDE interface for ruby-debug.

ruby-prof (0.16.2)
    Author: Shugo Maeda, Charlie Savage, Roger Pack, Stefan Kaes
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Fast Ruby profiler

ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
    Author: Mark Moseley
    Homepage: http://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby_core_source
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Retrieve Ruby core source files

rubygems-update (3.0.3)
    Authors: Jim Weirich, Chad Fowler, Eric Hodel, Luis Lavena, Aaron
    Patterson, Samuel Giddins, André Arko, Evan Phoenix, Hiroshi SHIBATA
    Homepage: https://rubygems.org
    Licenses: Ruby, MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    RubyGems is a package management framework for Ruby.

scanf (1.0.0)
    Author: David Alan Black
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/scanf
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    scanf is an implementation of the C function scanf(3).

sdbm (1.0.0)
    Author: Yukihiro Matsumoto
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/sdbm
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides a simple file-based key-value store with String keys and
    values.

shell (0.7)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/shell
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    An idiomatic Ruby interface for common UNIX shell commands.

slop (3.6.0)
    Author: Lee Jarvis
    Homepage: http://github.com/leejarvis/slop
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Simple Lightweight Option Parsing

stringio (0.0.2)
    Author: Nobu Nakada
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/stringio
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Pseudo IO on String

strscan (1.0.0)
    Author: Minero Aoki
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/strscan
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Provides lexical scanning operations on a String.

sync (0.5.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/sync
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A module that provides a two-phase lock with a counter.

test-unit (3.3.3, 3.2.9)
    Authors: Kouhei Sutou, Haruka Yoshihara
    Homepage: http://test-unit.github.io/
    Licenses: Ruby, PSFL
    Installed at (3.3.3): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (3.2.9): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    An xUnit family unit testing framework for Ruby.

thread_safe (0.3.6)
    Authors: Charles Oliver Nutter, thedarkone
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/thread_safe
    License: Apache-2.0
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Thread-safe collections and utilities for Ruby

thwait (0.1.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/thwait
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Watches for termination of multiple threads.

tracer (0.1.0)
    Author: Keiju ISHITSUKA
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/tracer
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Outputs a source level execution trace of a Ruby program.

tzinfo (1.2.5)
    Author: Philip Ross
    Homepage: http://tzinfo.github.io
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Daylight savings aware timezone library

webrick (1.4.2)
    Authors: TAKAHASHI Masayoshi, GOTOU YUUZOU, Eric Wong
    Homepage: https://www.ruby-lang.org
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    HTTP server toolkit

xml-simple (1.1.5)
    Author: Maik Schmidt
    Homepage: https://github.com/maik/xml-simple
    License: Ruby
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    A simple API for XML processing.

xmlrpc (0.3.0, 0.2.1)
    Author: SHIBATA Hiroshi
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/xmlrpc
    License: Ruby
    Installed at (0.3.0): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
                 (0.2.1): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    XMLRPC is a lightweight protocol that enables remote procedure calls
    over HTTP.

zeitwerk (2.1.9)
    Author: Xavier Noria
    Homepage: https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk
    License: MIT
    Installed at: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Efficient and thread-safe constant autoloader

zlib (1.0.0)
    Authors: Yukihiro Matsumoto, UENO Katsuhiro
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/zlib
    License: BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (default): C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

    Ruby interface for the zlib compression/decompression library
```

I am wondering why does it work with Ruby 2.4 package and fails to fetch gems for Ruby 2.6.3 package. Netbeans Ruby forums and mailing lists seem to have rolled off the history and #netbeans IRC seems idle and no one responds. I thank you in advance for any suggestions that you have.

P.S. Unless the Gem Manager works correctly, I can't debug any program - because debugger doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The failure occurs in `Gem::Util.glob_files_in_dir`, which is defined in RubyGems 3 as:

```
def self.glob_files_in_dir(glob, base_path)
  if RUBY_VERSION >= "2.5"
    Dir.glob(glob, base: base_path).map! {|f| File.expand_path(f, base_path) }
  else
    Dir.glob(File.expand_path(glob, base_path))
  end
end
```

The parameters passed to the method are:

```
glob = "did_you_mean-*.gemspec"
base_path = "C:/Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/specifications"
```

In older Ruby versions, this base_path parameter would result in `glob_files_in_dir` returning `[]`. Newer versions throw the argument error.

**Solution**

You can fix this issue by manually setting NetBean's gem path:

1. From the menu, select Tools > Ruby Platforms
2. Select your Ruby 2.6 platform
3. In the Gem Path list, select the existing value - eg "C:\Users\myuser.gem\ruby\2.6.0:C:\Ruby26\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0"
4. Click Remove
5. Click Add...
6. Enter the file name "C:\Ruby26\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0"
7. Click Open to select the folder
8. Click Close to close the dialog

In the end, the platform should look like:

[image: Ruby Platform Manager]